# Maximum uniqueness in pairs of numbers with a slight constraint

Tags: algorithm, max, unique, max-flow

Here's an algorithmic challenge for you,

I have a list of `[0..100]` pairs of numbers and I need to find the **maximum** number of **unique** "*left number*" while making sure there is **no more than 3** of the "*right number*".

Here's an example

- `(1, 1)`
- `(2, 1)`
- `(3, 1)`
- `(4, 1)`
- `(5, 1)`
- `(6, 1)`
- `(7, 1)`
- `(1, 2)`
- `(4, 2)`
- `(1, 3)`
- `(2, 3)`
- `(5, 4)`

And the result would be: **7**. We would take: `(3, 1)`, `(6, 1)`, `(7, 1)`, `(1, 2)`, `(4, 2)`, `(2, 3)` and `(5, 4)`.

For whatever reason I can't seem to find any other way than brute forcing it...

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express this problem as a maximum flow problem:

Make edges of capacity 1 from a source node to each of your left numbers.

Make edges of capacity 3 from each of your right numbers to a sink node.

Make edges of capacity 1 from left number a to right number b for each pair of the form (a, b).

Compute the maximum flow in this network from source to sink.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in the implementation, here's a ruby version of the [`push–relabel maximum flow algorithm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93relabel_maximum_flow_algorithm) with `relabel-to-front` selection rule.

```rb
def relabel_to_front(capacities, source, sink)
  n      = capacities.length
  flow   = Array.new(n) { Array.new(n, 0) }
  height = Array.new(n, 0)
  excess = Array.new(n, 0)
  seen   = Array.new(n, 0)
  queue  = (0...n).select { |i| i != source && i != sink }.to_a

  height[source] = n - 1
  excess[source] = Float::INFINITY
  (0...n).each { |v| push(source, v, capacities, flow, excess) }

  p = 0
  while p < queue.length
    u = queue[p]
    h = height[u]
    discharge(u, capacities, flow, excess, seen, height, n)
    if height[u] > h
      queue.unshift(queue.delete_at(p))
      p = 0
    else
      p += 1
    end
  end

  flow[source].reduce(:+)
end

def push(u, v, capacities, flow, excess)
  residual_capacity = capacities[u][v] - flow[u][v]
  send = [excess[u], residual_capacity].min
  flow[u][v] += send
  flow[v][u] -= send
  excess[u] -= send
  excess[v] += send
end

def discharge(u, capacities, flow, excess, seen, height, n)
  while excess[u] > 0
    if seen[u] < n
      v = seen[u]
      if capacities[u][v] - flow[u][v] > 0 && height[u] > height[v]
        push(u, v, capacities, flow, excess)
      else
        seen[u] += 1
      end
    else
      relabel(u, capacities, flow, height, n)
      seen[u] = 0
    end
  end
end

def relabel(u, capacities, flow, height, n)
  min_height = Float::INFINITY
  (0...n).each do |v|
    if capacities[u][v] - flow[u][v] > 0
      min_height = [min_height, height[v]].min
      height[u] = min_height + 1
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the code to transform the pairs of numbers into the capacities array of array

```rb
user_ids = Set.new
post_ids = Set.new

pairs.each do |p|
  user_ids << p[:user_id]
  post_ids << p[:post_id]
end

index_of_user_id = {}
index_of_post_id = {}

user_ids.each_with_index { |user_id, index| index_of_user_id[user_id] = 1 + index }
post_ids.each_with_index { |post_id, index| index_of_post_id[post_id] = 1 + index + user_ids.count }

source = 0
sink = user_ids.count + post_ids.count + 1
n = sink + 1

capacities = Array.new(n) { Array.new(n, 0) }
# source -> user_ids = 1
index_of_user_id.values.each { |i| capacities[source][i] = 1 }
# user_ids -> post_ids = 1
pairs.each { |p| capacities[index_of_user_id[p[:user_id]]][index_of_post_id[p[:post_id]]] = 1 }
# post_ids -> sink = 3
index_of_post_id.values.each { |i| capacities[i][sink] = 3 }
```